# How can we use JSon response of an API as JSon body for another API in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm working with two API's 
1)to "get customer" details 
2) to "modify customer".

Body required for "Modify customer" is same as the response fetched from "get customer" API. Now question is how i can save the response of "get Customer" API to use it as body for "modify customer" API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSR223 Post processor with the following code:-

```
vars.put("responseVar",prev.getResponseDataAsString());
```

This will put response body in "responseVar" variable. Fetch it using ${responseVar}

Hope this helps.